# SQL - How to SELECT the best two months which are next to each other

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

How to `select` in PostgreSQL the best two months from `Table`.

```
Table:

ID Month   Value
1  2019-06  100
2  2019-07  120
3  2019-08  70
4  2019-09  200
5  2019-10  100
6  2019-11  50
```

I would like to select ID where sum(Value) of two months which are next to each other is the highest.
In the following case the result will be:

```
4 2019-09
5 2019-10
```

where the sum of values is equal to `300`.

Comment: *next to each other* means consecutive ids or consecutive months?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the data on one row using `join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.month = t1.month + interval '1 month'
order by t1.value + t.value desc
limit 1;
```

Getting separate rows is trickier.  You can easily get the first row using `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lead(value, 1, 0) over (order by month) as next_value
      from t
     ) t
order by (value + next_value) desc
limit 1;
```

Getting the second month is much trickier.  I am thinking that the simplest method is to unpivot the first results:

```
select t.*
from (select t1, t2
      from t t1 join
           t t2
           on t2.month = t1.month + interval '1 month'
      order by t1.value + t.value desc
      limit 1
     ) cross join lateral
     unnest(array[t1, t2]) t
order by t.month;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses solely window functions and that does not assume that `month` is of a `date`-like datatype.

This works as follows:

- first rank records per increasing month with `row_number()` (aliased as `rn`) and compute the sum of the current and previous value (aliased as `vals`)
- rank records by `vals` (aliased `rnk`)
- exhibit the row number the record that has the highest `vals` (aliased `rn_max`)
- finally pull out the this record and the preceeding one (ie the one that has the previous row number)

Query:

```
select id, month, value
from (
    select t.*, first_value(rn) over(order by rnk) rn_max
    from (
        select t.*, rank() over(order by vals desc) rnk
        from (
            select 
                t.*, 
                value + lag(value, 1, 0) over (order by month) vals,
                row_number() over(order by month) rn
            from mytable t
        ) t
    ) t
) t
where rn in (rn_max, rn_max - 1)
order by month
```

**[Step-by-step demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6b29a3221ade95bbd64296bdb38ee7b0)**:

```
id | month   | value
-: | :------ | ----:
 4 | 2019-09 |   200
 5 | 2019-10 |   100
```